# Using a transistor as diode

Tags: diodes, npn

What are the advantages of using a transistor as a diode after interconnecting its collector and base?

Comment: Current mirror?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.  If you have a circuit that uses this technique then post it.  Otherwise, do your own homework.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's homework

Answer (score 11):

One advantage can be found: In linear scale there's very sharp knee in the forward current vs. voltage curve. In logarithmic scale it's quite a straight line. I had once to build a safety circuit to an existing custom digital display resistance meter. The safety circuit had to guarantee the meter will never output more than 1,5 volt to the device under test.

The safety circuit was needed for 2 reasons:

- people in a factory wanted to see something so simple they could understand and verify. Digital measurement devices and integrated circuits weren't such things. Those people made detonators.
- there was internal safety code which said that the open circuit voltage must be 1,5 volts or less, no matter there's resistors and a fuse which would limit the current in case of faults. That wasn't a problem with devices which used only a single 1,5V battery. Electronic devices needed more.

The resistance meter was a DVM with a current source. It had a differential preamp to scale the result to DVM's range from the usual measurement voltage level.

The safety circuit was not allowed to disturb the resistance measurement. Usual diodes and zener diodes conducted too much and no complex circuits were considered reliable. A transistor base and collector together  (actually 2 transistors) were considered to be a good enough last resort limiter:

[image]

A and B were soldered directly to the test connectors.

Comment: could you demonstrate your transistor configuration please?

Comment: @Ilya the story is completed.

Answer (score 10):

Because the transistor as a diode has an emission coefficient that is close to one, it behaves in a more ideal manner than a diode.

Hence it is frequently used in applications such as current mirrors and temperature sensing. By running matched transistors (or one transistor time-shared) at two or three different currents you can sense temperature quite accurately without calibration. Two currents (typically about 10:1 apart) eliminates much of the device-to-device variation, and three (typically something like (1:6:16) can be used to cancel out the resistive component in the semiconductor (base resistance) and connecting traces. That is how the CPU temperature in your PC is measured (an on-chip diode-connected transistor).

Answer (score 6):

It depends upon context. What is it being used for?

Actually, if you connect the collector to the base you are not just using the base-emitter junction, you are using all the junctions and the transistor is acting as a negative feedback amplifier with the collector being fed back to the base.

A transistor connected as a diode actually follows the Ebers-Moll equations much more closely than the great majority diodes. If you are using it in a circuit where that is important it functions much better than an ordinary diode. Ordinary diodes not only do not follow the theoretical curves well there are also likely to be significant differences between different diodes.

It is mainly used in circuits such as Log and anti-log generators where such characteristics are important.

It has many disadvantages in other applications that have been mentioned in other answers so it is not commonly used.

Answer (score 3):

Years ago, I used Germanium transistors, configured as diodes (by interconnecting their base and emitter or base and collector), in crystal radios.

[image]

The advantage was a forward voltage as low as 0.1 V.

Comment: base-emitter shorting does different things.

Answer (score -2):

It only has drawbacks. The collector current has limitation depending on the collector voltage(base is connected to ground) while the forward current of the diode can theoretically reach infinite value.

Comment: another big disadvantage is the reverse breakdown voltage is often very low (like 5V)

Comment: Yes BeB00 you are correct.

Comment: I noticed people use that in log and anti-log configurations. Why is that?

Comment: Maybe because you can regulate the output voltage by changing the base and emitter resistance.

Comment: @ArtOfElectronics - as mentioned in my answer, transistor connected diodes follow the theoretical exponential laws much more closely than diodes. This, in turn, is because of the current density that they operate at.

Comment: @BeB00 Using base-emitter as a zenner diode can be pretty much legitimate.

Comment: @fraxinus sure, but that makes it a pretty bad general purpose diode

Comment: Why `base is connected to ground`? Consider connection like from user287001's diagram. Certainly not a ground!